Different values in matplotlib piechart from the pandas dataframe
Check this code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Região': ['NORTE', 'SUDESTE', 'NORDESTE', 'CENTRO OESTE', 'SUL'],
    'PNT "Real" sobre mercado BT (%)': [52.75, 15.04, 12.82, 8.23, 8.04]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.set_index('Região', inplace=True)

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')  
ax.patch.set_linewidth(1) 
ax.pie(data['PNT "Real" sobre mercado BT (%)'].values, textprops={'size': 'smaller'}, labels=data.index, autopct='%1.2f%%', wedgeprops={'edgecolor':'black'})
ax.axis('equal')
# fig.savefig('pnts_sobre_BT_Regioes.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()

I am getting this figure as result:

Why are the values in the figure different from the ones in data?

Because your data do not add up to 100 %. The keyword autopct means that percentages are calculated with respect to the sum of your data.

I understand, thanks. I am going to change the figure for a table then.

As @Joooeey mentioned, the values you have do not add up to 100%.
If you want the pie chart to show the real values instead, try:
...
ax.pie(data['PNT "Real" sobre mercado BT (%)'].values, textprops={'size': 'smaller'}, labels=data.index, autopct=lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x * df['PNT "Real" sobre mercado BT (%)'].sum() / 100), wedgeprops={'edgecolor':'black'})
...

